# Google Apps Script each sheet different calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple sheets with different dates and different calendar ids. The intention is to have the script go over each sheet and import it in the calendar with the corresponding calander id. I have it working for one sheet/calendar, but i cant figure out how to expand the code to go over each sheet. This is what i have that works for one sheet/calendar:

```
function scheduleshifts() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var BBB = spreadsheet.getRange("BO1").getValue();
  var CCC = "BL2:"
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange(CCC+BBB).getValues();
  for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++){
    var shift = signups[x];
    var startTime = shift[0];
    var endTime = shift[1];
    var title = "Werken";

    eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime);

  }
}
function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar').addItem("Schedule shifts now", 'scheduleshifts').addToUi();

}
```

Comment: When you say multiple sheets do you mean class spreadsheet or class sheet?

Comment: I am sorry Cooper I am not sure what you mean. But if I understand it correctly it is the multiple sheets in one spreadsheet file.

Answer (score 0):

#### Creating Events from multiple sheets and muliple calendar ids

```
function scheduleshifts() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//included sheets. If you are always using all sheets then remove this line and the filter section.
  const inclshts = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"];
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(s => ~inclshts.indexOf(s.getName()) ).forEach(sh => {
    let eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(sh.getRange("B2").getDisplayValue());//id is in each sheet
    let signups = sh.getRange(`BL2:${sh.getRange("BO1").getValues()}`);
    Logger.log(`BL2:${sh.getRange("BO1").getValues()}`);
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(sh.getRange("BO1").getValues()));
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(signups));
    signups.forEach((r,i)=>{
      eventCal.createEvent("Werken",new Date(r[1]),new Date(r[2]);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I tried implementing piece of code but I now I get the error "TypeError: signups.forEach is not a function".

Comment: I had a  typo in the code try it again

Comment: I tried, but now I get "TypeError: signups.forEach is not a functionDetails"

Comment: Do you maybe got an idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Please provide me with the results of the Logger.logs that I have added

Comment: Thanks for helping. It says: "information BL2:$BM$5", "information [["$BM$5"]]
" and "information { }. "

Comment: do you have an idea why the second eventCal returns Null